# Having problems when using mirror modifier during retopology of model with bias offset

Tags: modeling, mirror, polycount

So it is the 1-st time I need to retopology the model, I extracted the model from my very old project where it was set in the scene, rotated numerous times and when I`m using mirror modifier at retopology stage it obviusly does not split model the way it is supposed to be. I tried to aligh the model to the center of the grid but no luck so far as it probably had its own fulcrum or so. So either it is possible to somehow use mirror modifier correctly or align the model to the center. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The mirror modifier is relative to the object's origin and local rotation. You could manually move the origin and reset the local rotation, or use an empty in the mirror modifier 'mirror object' slot for full external control of the mirror behaviour!

Comment: Thanks! I`m going to try it